# Access an attribute from a Mailer in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, attributes, parent-child, actionmailer, nested-attributes

I am trying to access the name of the seller (seller.name) in the following mailer.
Resa is child of Seller (Seller has_many resas and Resa belongs to Seller).

in **app/mailers/resa_mailer.rb**

```
class ResaMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: 'need@dipozit.com'
  def request_mail(resa)
    @email = resa.request_email
    @maturity_date = resa.maturity_date
    @amount = resa.amount
    @currency = resa.currency
    @request_expiry_date = resa.request_expiry_date
    @description = resa.description
    @seller = Seller.where(["seller_id = resa.seller_id"])
    mail to: @email, subject: @seller.name+' requests a deposit'
  end
end
```

which is called in **resas_controller #create**:

```
    class ResasController < ApplicationController
before_action :set_resa, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
before_action :authenticate_seller!

def new
  @resa = current_seller.resas.new
end

def create
  @resa = current_seller.resas.new(resa_params)
  @resa.seller_id = current_seller.mp_id
  respond_to do |format|
    if @resa.save
      ResaMailer.request_mail(@resa).deliver
      format.html { redirect_to @resa, notice: 'Resa was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @resa }
    else
      format.html { render action: 'new' }
      format.json { render json: @resa.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

private
  # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
  def set_resa
    @resa = Resa.find(params[:id])
  end

  # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
  def resa_params
    params.require(:resa).permit(:resa_date, :maturity_date, :amount, :currency, :request_expiry_date, :request_status, :maturity_status, :description, :seller_id, :buyer_id, :request_email)
  end
```

end

Answer (score 1):

Your code is a bit confused:

```
@seller = Seller.where(["seller_id = resa.seller_id"]).name
puts @seller.inspect
puts @seller
puts @seller.name
```

Shows that the first definition of @seller is already the name (Seller.where([...]).name). Then you try to call @seller.name again, and get the error because you're trying to call the 'name' method on a string, because it's already the name.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I deleted the 3 puts and the error disappeared but instead of having the name (that is "Bill) I get "Seller".
Any idea ?